# add rows at set time of the day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to automatically add a row (with predefined cell values) at a specific time of the day?
I.e. at 15:30 each day I want to append this row ("today'sdate", "1", "ok", "4", "DS") automaticlaly (so the script should be triggered by current time)

Thanks

Not good with this code, can I do this without script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts can be run at specified hour. In Apps Script edition window, go to **Triggers** in left panel and then add a new trigger. In the dropdown list **Select type of time based trigger** select **Day timer**. Below, you can specified hour at which your script would be run (I guess you cannot specifiy exact minute, I guess it will be run at around 30 minutes in specified hours).

Or you can do it another way. You can set the trigger to launch every minute and then inside your script you can run a simple *if statement* which would check current hour and minute. If it matches the time you want, the script would be executed.